# Microsoft webdriver and selenium webdriver causing visual studio build errors

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-webdriver

I am trying to use Selenium Webdriver in visual studio to check a website. Everything worked fine when I was using just Chromedriver, but now that I have added the Microsoft Webdriver to test the site using Edge I am having issues. I made sure to download the correct version of the webdriver for my os build.

Every other time I go to run my test visual studio encounters a build error.

> Warning        Could not copy "C:\Desktop\UnitTestProject3\packages\Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver.17.17134.0\build..\driver\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe" to "C:\Desktop\UnitTestProject3\UnitTestProject3\bin\Debug\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe". Beginning retry 9 in 1000ms. The process cannot access the file 'C:\Desktop\UnitTestProject3\UnitTestProject3\bin\Debug\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' because it is being used by another process. The file is locked by: "Microsoft Web Driver (12804), Microsoft Web Driver (12340), Microsoft Web Driver (1124), Microsoft Web Driver (19756), Microsoft Web Driver (2592), Microsoft Web Driver (12736), Microsoft Web Driver (19604), Microsoft Web Driver (12428), Microsoft Web Driver (18604), Microsoft Web Driver (10500), Microsoft Web Driver (12724)"

If i dismiss the error and then run the test one more time it runs fine. Has anyone ran into this before?
Any help would be appreciated! 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check your processes, May be MicrosoftWebDriver.exe is still running in process and that's why you would get build error.

If script fails abruptly, you need to handle your code to quit driver. Otherwise driver will remain active in processes.